# How can I label subfigures as (4a), (4b), instead of (a), (b)?

Tags: subfloats, labels

I have a figure with two subfigures. I do not want a label for the entire figure, only for the subfigures, but if I only label the subfigures, they are just labeled (a) and (b) by default. This may be confusing to the reader because in the text the reference appears as "Figure 4a".

How can I change the labeling so that the figures read (4a) and (4b)?

I was unable to find an answer when searching pre-existing questions.

Thanks for the assistance.

Here is a minimal working example which replicates the issue:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[]{example-image}
  \caption{Text of Caption 4a}
\label{fig:4a-label}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[]{example-image}
  \caption{Text of Caption 4b}
\label{fig:4b-label}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edit: It is also necessary that references to the Figure still show (4a) and (4b).

Comment: Please add a small example document. How do you add teh subfigures and how do you add the references to them?

Comment: Thanks, I edited in a simplified version of the code for this particular section. If more information is needed I can gladly include that as well.

Comment: Please make the code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) Instead of your actual images, you can use `example-image`. Is it intentional that your two subfigures have individual captions each but not a common caption?

Comment: Dear @leandriis, I have created a MWE and edited it in. Yes, I don't want a label for the entire figure. An alternative solution would just be to hide the labels and write "Fig (4b)" manually in the caption text... as long as one can still \ref the subfigures and they appear as "Figure 4b" etc.

Comment: Just add `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks, that was it

Comment: @Bernard Wait, no. Now the references show "Figure 44a" instead of "Figure 4a".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggest @Bernard in his comment, but then for citing sub figures you need to use `\subref` command:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}} % suggested by Bernard

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Text of Caption 4a}
\label{fig:4a-label}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Text of Caption 4b}
\label{fig:4b-label}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Common caption}
\label{fig:4-label}
\end{figure}
See \subref{fig:4a-label} and \subref{fig:4b-label} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If you like that sub images references looks like

[image]

then add in preamble (after `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{...}`) code line

```
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
```

Comment: Works very well, thanks a lot for the help.